# proper way to set background image to IPad App

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have a working IPad App. I built everything on a default white screen and I want to add an image to background of the image. I read a couple of articles and most of the suggest to create a new UIImage with the background image and stretch it to the full screen. I tried that but I am using a couple UIImage to display the photos taken and my UIImage s seem to stay at the  back of the background and they don't get shown.

What is the proper way to set the background of IPad App?

this is the screenshot of my IPad App

[image: here is the screenshot]

Comment: you should edit your question to show a screenshot of what your app currently looks like; it *sounds* like you have a number of images you are trying to display at the same time in the background of your app.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I added the screenshot

Comment: thanks for editing your question; now, what's wrong with your app?  are the images simply not being displayed or do you want them to be stretched to the width of the screen or?  If they are not being displayed, can you edit your question to show the code of where you attempt to set the imageviews to those images?

Comment: I just want to set a background image. I just dragged and dropped a new UIImage to use it as a background image. But the newly created UIImage stayed at the front and didnt let my 3 small UIImage object appear

Comment: I'd help you further but it looks like you've got a few good answers already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Follow these steps :**

**1)** Add `UIImageView` to your `UIView`.

**2)** Fill it with your Background `UIImage`.

**3)** Select your Background `UIImageView` and Select **"Send to Back"** Option....

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. thanks to everyone but you answered the question I was asking. I will mark it as answered

Answer (score 1):

The key is your view hierarchy. If you do not want to hassle around with moving the subviews along and sendings ome to back and some to front, then start with a proper view hierarchy from the beginning. 
Basic rules are: the subviews overlay their superviews. 
If siblings overlay each other, then the last one added is shown.

Your view hierarchy could be:

```
\UIView        (A: the underlying self.view from the view controller's point of view.) 
  \UIImageView    (B: the view for your background image. Empty or hidden from start.)
  \UIView         (C: Container for all of your views, no background color, no background image)
    \UIImageView      (C1: One of your picuters)
    \UIImageView      (C2: One of your picuters)
    \UIImageView      (C3: One of your picuters)
    \UILabel          (C4: One of your labels)
    \ ...
```

Build up your view hierarchy. And when you need to add or change the background then assign the appropriate UIImage ot the View B.

Certainly, there is more than one way to achieve this. However, I personally thinkthat some proper view hierarchy works best, regardless whether you do that in IB or programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to create a UIImageView and set it to the size of your view, and put all the others View in fron of it. The tutorials that you read are giving you the right way.

If you do not want to add an image, only a color you can set the background color of your view to this color.

You can use this code to send the ImageView to the back:

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:YouBackgroundImageView];
```

**EDIT**

Because you posted and XIB screenshot:

Your background image view must be in the first position, like this image:[image]