# Bring UIImageView on top of the other UIImageViews in my main view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

I have a lot of `UIImageViews` in my main view, some of these have images, others are blank. I have setup code that will check which `UIImageView` currently contains an image. At the same time, this code will take care of allowing a `UIImageView` with an image to be moved around.

Now what happens is this: when moving a selected `UIImageView` around (for some reason and quite randomly), the image will not stay on top of the other `UImageViews` in the screen. The reason why I say that this is random is because it will stay on top of some of the other views, but not on top of others.

The behavior is unexpected, several problems arise:

1. Visually it looks bad; there is no reason why a touched `UIImageView` should slip under another.
2. The way I have the code going is to allow `UIImageViews` to be moved only if they contain an image. So if the `UIImageView` goes under another who does not contain an image, I cannot touch and move it again. It looks like it is stuck in place.

Please note that I have not been setting subviews at all for this code, thus why this behavior occurs is beyond me.

So what my question boils down to, is there any way that I can tell the code to:

- Get the object that was touched.
- If it is a `UIImageView` with an image, then allow me to move the `UIImageView`.
- allow this `UIImageView` to supersede (be on top of) all other `UIImageViews`.

Code reference:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{UITouch *touch;
    UITouch *touch;    
    CGPoint touchLocation;

    for (UIImageView *fruit in fruitArray)
    {
        // Check that the UIImageView contains an image
        if([fruit image] != nil)
        {
            // Get the touch event.
            touch = [touches anyObject];
            // Get the location for the touched object within the view.
            touchLocation = [touch locationInView:[self view]];

            // Bring the UIImageView touch location to the image's center.
            if([touch view] == fruit)
            {
                fruit.center = touchLocation;
            }
        }
    }

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    //allow the selected event (in our case a UIImageView) to be dragged
    [self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Thank you for your help! Let me know if you need a better explanation

Comment: [self.view bringSubviewToFront:imageView];

Comment: excellent mate! mind putting this as an answer? I'd like to give you credit

Comment: Take a look at my Answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16768594/1603072

Comment: @Vin this is very awesome too, thank you for your contribution I will use this method from now on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:imageView];
```

This was what you were looking for...

Comment: exactly, I will edit this to match the code above. Thanks a lot! By the way do you have any reference to where I can find this in the documentation? I couldn't see it anywhere.