# How to put my 2 existing buttons to the foreground, they are now behind an imageview

Tags: iphone, ios

The question is in the title.
There must be a simpel way to do this I guess?

There is an imageview on the screen, there doesn't have to be any interaction with it.
On the imageview I want 2 small buttons left and right but the buttons were created (and the code is written) before the imageview. How do I set this imageview to the background? :)

Comment: Take a look at My Answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16768594/1603072

Comment: [viewThatContainButton bringsubviewtoFront:button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking at your xib or stoyboard (where you can see the layout), you can use the View Controller scene which is a list of all of the objects, views etc on your Apps layout.

You can click and drag the UI image view so its above the buttons in the list. I'm guessing it's just defaulted to being on top of the buttons.

Answer (score 3):

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:yourImageView];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add buttons as subview of imageview.
you can write below code for that:

```
[imageView addSubview:button1];
[imageView addSubview:button2];
```

So buttons will be appear in foreground.

Comment: Or you can just drag the imageView above the buttons in the View controller scene in the storyboard I just noticed :p Thank anyway! Problem solved :)

Answer (score -1):

In your storyboard, choose your viewController by clicking on it. On left side you can see hierarchy like [left side view in this image](http://www.google.co.in/imgres?um=1&sa=N&biw=1280&bih=670&hl=en&tbm=isch&tbnid=hwTRCNcjXFncdM:&imgrefurl=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707540/visually-modifying-a-uitoolbar-from-xcode-storyboard&docid=qJfNYPzRMOyoyM&imgurl=http://i.imgur.com/22sxv.png&w=1152&h=609&ei=WbK4UYCfD8XsrAf3zIBQ&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:2,s:0,i:86&iact=rc&dur=3894&page=1&tbnh=163&tbnw=309&start=0&ndsp=12&tx=109&ty=65). Check if your imageView is below, in hierarchy, to your 2 buttons. If it is, then drag the imageView and move it above both the buttons. 
**Concept :** The view that is below in hierarchy is visible on top of all the views above it.